# Optimizing Slow T-SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on creating a stored procedure for a table in my database; however, it runs extremely slow due to a large number of joins that must be performed. I am trying to think of a way to optimize the query so that I do not need to perform so many left joins, but I am having trouble finding a way to do this. My code looks like the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STS]
AS
DECLARE @t0 table(Id nvarchar(7), Date1 date, TIV float, [1mo] float, RAN nvarchar(50), SAN nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t0(Id, Date1, TIV, [1mo], RAN, SAN)
SELECT Id, Date1, TIV, TMR, RAN, SAN
FROM dbo.History
WHERE (Date1 IS NOT NULL) AND (Valid IS NULL OR Valid <> 0) AND (include <> 0)

DECLARE @t1 table(Id nvarchar(7), Date1 date, TIV float, [3mo] float, RAN nvarchar(50), SAN nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t1(Id, Date1, TIV, [3mo], RAN, SAN) 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Series(3)

DECLARE @t2 table(Id nvarchar(7), Date1 date, TIV float, [6mo] float, RAN nvarchar(50), SAN nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t2(Id, Date1, TIV, [6mo], RAN, SAN) 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Series(6)

DECLARE @t3 table(Id nvarchar(7), Date1 date, TIV float, [9mo] float, RAN nvarchar(50), SAN nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t3(Id, Date1, TIV, [9mo], RAN, SAN) 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Series(9)


 SELECT t0.*, Join2.[3mo], Join2.[6mo], Join2.[9mo]
 FROM @t0 as t0
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT t1.*, Join1.[6mo], Join1.[9mo]
     FROM @t1 as t1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT t2.*, t3.[9mo]
         FROM @t2 as t2
         LEFT OUTER JOIN @t3 as t3 
         ON t2.Id = t3.Id AND t2.Date1 = t3.Date1 AND t2.RAN = t3.RAN AND 
             t2.SAN = t3.SAN) as Join1
     ON t1.Id = Join1.Id AND t1.Date1 = Join1.Date1 AND t1.RAN = Join1.RAN AND
             t1.SAN = Join1.SAN) as Join2
 ON t0.Id = Join2.Id AND t0.Date1 = Join2.Date1 AND t0.RAN = Join2.RAN AND
             t0.SAN = Join2.SAN
```

Is there a simple way to optimize this slow query, or do I need to think of a new way to do this altogether?

Comment: What is the func Series()? Making `dbo.Series(X)` work for a set of [3,6,9] seems an good idea

Comment: The func Series() actually executes in a couple of seconds. The joins themselves create the large overhead, and they occur outside of Series().

Comment: There is a lot of low hanging performance fruit in here. You have a number of nonSARGable predicates. When you have <> it means a scan no matter what indexing you have in place. The table variables as JamesZ pointed out. Why even bother with pulling that data into a variable or temp table anyway? Just join to your table valued function. That table valued function might be another location to gain some performance if it is anything more than a single query. I suspect the final query can be optimized too but it is nearly impossible to read in this format.

Comment: You actually don't  have a large number of joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end of the final join

This article explains a lot about table variables and temporary tables: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

Comment: You might want to explain why you think that would help (e.g. sometihng about parameter sniffing)

Answer (score 3):

The problem often caused by table variables is that because there are no statistics for them, estimated row count is 1, which can lead to really bad join performance. The first thing I would recommend to do is try to change them to temporary tables. Since you didn't mention how much rows there are, it's hard to say if indexes on those temp. tables will help, but that's something you might try out too.

If the query is still slow, looking at statistics io output to see the I/O counts and query plan to see what happens should help to understand what's causing the problems.

Answer (score 3):

This does appear to be overly complicated and table variable are not very efficient for larger data sets.

```
   SELECT h.Id, h.Date1, h,TIV, h.[1mo], h.RAN, h.SAN, 
                threemonth.somefield as [3mo], sixmonth.somefield as[6mo],  ninemonth.somefield as[9mo]
    FROM dbo.History h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Series(3) threemonth 
        ON h.Id = threemonth.Id AND h.Date1 =threemonth.Date1 
            AND h.RAN = threemonth.RAN AND   h.SAN = threemonth.SAN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Series(6) sixmonth 
    ON sixmonth.Id = threemonth.Id AND sixmonth.Date1 =threemonth.Date1 
            AND sixmonth.RAN = threemonth.RAN AND  sixmonth.SAN = threemonth.SAN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Series(9) ninemonth  
    ON sixmonth.Id = ninemonth.Id AND sixmonth.Date1 =ninemonth.Date1 
            AND sixmonth.RAN = ninemonth.RAN AND   sixmonth.SAN = ninemonth.SAN
    WHERE (h.Date1 IS NOT NULL) 
            AND (h.Valid IS NULL OR h.Valid <> 0) 
            AND (h.include <> 0)
```

Now that it is simplified you can see the pain points better.

First the table function will not use any indexes for the joins. Therefore it may be better not to use it if a large number of records are being returned.

Also the fields that are being joined on are not very efficient even when they use indexes because you are joining on dates and varchars as well as ints. This may need a redesign in your table structures or table function to give you something better for joins.

Without understanding what the dbo.series() function does, it is hard to make a specific recommendation. However if h.Id is unique (and it probably is the PK) it may not be necessary to do all the other join conditions. Again this depends soley on the work that happens in the table valued function.  I am just making a guess based on years of database experience and knowledge of hundreds of databases. If you can in any way simply the joins you wlll get better performance. Remeber though that in trying to simplify, you need to check each step along teh way to make sure that you still return the same results.

Finally you have the problem of the Where clause. Your two problems here are the OR condition which can often be replaced with a UNION ALL for better performance and the <> conditions. One way I can think of to improve the <> problem is to fill a temp table that is indexed with the acceptable values and then use that. You would likely only see a big performance increase though if you had thousands of possible values. If the possible values are in a lookup table you could join to that using a not exists clause to filter out the 0.

Comment: I would pull the where up into the join and use isnull(h.Valid, 1)  <> 0

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting a primary key on your table variables.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @t1 
table   (
          Id nvarchar(7), 
          Date1 date, 
          TIV float, 
          [3mo] float, 
          RAN nvarchar(50), 
          SAN nvarchar(50),
          Primary Key (Id, Date1, RAN, SAN)
        )
INSERT INTO @t1(Id, Date1, TIV, [3mo], RAN, SAN) 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Series(3)
```

This will cause the inserts in to the table variables to be a little slower, but the joins should be a lot faster.

Comment: Or they could just reference the table directly. What purpose does even and indexed table variable serve?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the table function, this may provide better performance than joining directly to the tables.  Usually it does not, but it can happen.

Comment: Cool but that is the whole table.  I have never had a table variable out perform a table unless I was used it to extract a small subset.

Comment: @blam, remeber this is a table valued function not a table that iti si refernceing. That is not indexed either.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunateky you can't really cut out the joins as you need them to get the correct reults. I would try to look at what the join is on and then check if there is an index on that column if not look at creating one. That is the only way I really see to possibly increase perfomance on the query. Becareful though keep a record of changes made because some indexes could cause it to run slower. Just keep some metrics of run times.